# Cannot set QVariantMap as QML property

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qml, qvariant

I want to export a `QVariantMap` property to QML, so I'm doing

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantMap myData READ myData)
```

and in myData() function I just do

```
QVariantMap map;
map.insert("ExampleKey", "key");
return map;
```

and in QML either

```
myData.ExampleKey //undefined
```

or

```
myData["ExampleKey"] //undefined
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to be able to use this as a simple JS object?

Comment: You have the Q_OBJECT macro in your class that inherits QObject, yeah?

Comment: Also, the read function is definitely not called (qdebug doesn't show up)

Comment: Test your class as a context property like in my example...

Comment: That would take a lot of time and I'm sure it works outside a context property as well

Comment: It would take a lot of time to expose a context property? It is a very minor addition for testing. It would help localizing whether your issue is the class and/or the way you try to expose it. Anyway, we do need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: OK, lemme try it as a context property

Comment: It still returns undefined even as a context property

Comment: Show us your class source please.

Comment: Here's the header (where most of the code is). The cpp only has the Q_INVOKABLE methods https://paste.kde.org/phwifivrh/pmekma

Answer (score -1):

Thanks BaCaRoZzo for finding the optimal answer. Basically QML JavaScript uses QVariantMap for its array. Nothing more needs to be done, use JavaScript array and you get QVariantMap and it is transportable to C++.

*The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QVariantList and JavaScript arrays, and between QVariantMap and JavaScript objects.*

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object

Comment: [Javascript-side example in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object).